# What is wrong with my simple for-loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm having a bit of trouble with my for-loop, I want to enter 1 number in an int array inside a for-loop which shall loop 4 times. But the output goes instantly to "Please enter the 4th number" as if the variable i is 4 from the start.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int PIN[4] = {};
    string txtNr ="1st";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
      if(i=0)
        txtNr = "1st";
      if(i=1)
        txtNr = "2nd";
      if(i=2)
        txtNr = "3rd";
      if(i=3)
        txtNr = "4th";
      cout << "Please enter the " << txtNr <<" number: ";
      cin >> PIN[i];
    }


        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
           cout << PIN[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

Anyone got a clue?
If I enter a number the last output is for example

0
0
0
1

Comment: [Turn on/up your compiler warnings.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/381d18b58f23bed4)

Comment: Use `==` for comparison. The `=` is for assignment. Your compiler alerts you if you follow @chris's recommendation :-)

Comment: Ha, what the legend common suck bug!

Comment: @chris it may be impossible, as it depends on IDE and compiler he uses.

Comment: @cupidon4uk, GCC, Clang, and MSVC all warn about this. I'm not sure about ICC or anything else (and if OP is using Turbo, I give up).

Comment: Use a debugger.  This issue would be caught quickly by using a debugger and executing line by line and *watching* the variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `=` to `==` to check for equality in the `if(...)` statements.

Just a plain `=` changes the value of `i`, just like a usual assignment.

Also, I would recommend you to read [C++ Style Guide from Google](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml).

After that your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int PIN[4] = {};
    string txtNr ="1st";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
      if(i == 0)
        txtNr = "1st";
      if(i == 1)
        txtNr = "2nd";
      if(i == 2)
        txtNr = "3rd";
      if(i == 3)
        txtNr = "4th";
      cout << "Please enter the " << txtNr <<" number: ";
      cin >> PIN[i];
    }


        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
           cout << PIN[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: You are using "=" where you mean to be using "==".  The single "=" will assign the value to `i` and always set the condition of the `if` statement to `true` except when you assign a zero.

Comment: Just so you know, a lot of people do not recommend Google's C++ style guide.

Comment: @chris 
it's still better :D
btw, Could you recommend something else?

Comment: @Logicrat What if you are assigning `false`, or a `null` value, or anything else that will evaluate to `false`? Just saying that assignments will *always evaluate to true unless you assign `0`* is incorrect.

Comment: @cupidon4uk, I don't use a particular one. I'm not sure which ones are popular.

Comment: @Josh within the context of the code shown, the variable `i` is declared `int`. A reasonable compiler will convert `false` or `null` will convert those to a zero in oder to assign it to the variable `i`. And the code given uses only integers. I did not intend to generalize about all expressions that can appear in `if` statements, only the several (unintended) assignments to `i` within the given question;

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot about that one, I feel stupid now!

Answer (score 3):

You are using `if(i=3)` instead of `if(i==3)` which is affecting the value of `i` instead of comparing it.